# Header based routing in ASP.NET Core

Tags: routes, asp.net-core

I'm trying to route requests to different controllers based on a HTTP header sent to the service.

in my `Configure` method, I have

```
app.MapWhen(ctx => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ctx.Request.Headers["Magic"]), DoStuff);
```

My issue is that I have no idea how to specify controllers, or even modify the route

```
 private static void DoStuff(IApplicationBuilder app)
 {
    /// ?!? \\\
 }
```

Ideally, I'd like that if the header `Magic: Missile` is sent, to rewrite the route to be `/Missile`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

While writing a custom middleware is certainly a good option, another option would be to create an action constraint (by implementing the **IActionContraint** interface).  This would allow you to decorate your methods with an attribute which dictates the header 
/ value that must be provided in the request in order for a given method to be invoked.

I found this to be particularly helpful when working with WebHooks where the external system uses a single URL for all hooks, and uses a header to differentiate the different action types.

Here is what a simple implementation of this attribute could look like:

```
public class HttpHeaderAttribute : Attribute, IActionConstraint
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public HttpHeaderAttribute (string header, string value)
    {
        Header = header;
        Value = value;
    }

    public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
    {
        if (context.RouteContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(Header, out var value))
        {
            return value[0] == Value;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int Order => 0;
}
```

And here's a sample of how you could use it:

```
    [HttpPost, Route("webhook"), HttpHeader("X-Drchrono-Event", "PATIENT_CREATE")]
    public IActionResult DrChronoPatientCreate(WebHookData data)
    {

    }

    [HttpPost, Route("webhook"), HttpHeader("X-Drchrono-Event", "PATIENT_MODIFY")]
    public IActionResult DrChronoPatientModify(WebHookData data)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 8):

I ended up writing a custom middleware to rewrite the uri before hitting the mvc layer. Works nicely!

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    const string apiPath = "/api";

    var magic context.Request.Headers["Magic"];

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(magic))
    {
        return _next.Invoke(context);
    }

    var path = context.Request.Path.ToUriComponent();

    if (!path.StartsWith(apiPath))
    {
        return _next.Invoke(context);
    }

    path = string.Concat(path.Skip(apiPath.Length));
    path = $"{apiPath}/{magic}{path}";
    context.Request.Path = path;

    return _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried, but action contraints, such as in the accepted answer, are a cleaner way to do it