# ASP.NET Core Resolve Controller and call Action by name

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-5

I have a generic catch all controller/action that receive files, parse the json content and find out the controller name and action name to be called from that.

Here my previous .NET Framework (old ASP) implementation which worked great:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> Run(PackingSlip packingSlip, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    var controllerName = packingSlip.service_name;
    var actionName = packingSlip.service_object;

    // get the controller
    var ctrlFactory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
    var ctrl = ctrlFactory.CreateController(this.Request.RequestContext, controllerName) as Controller;
    var ctrlContext = new ControllerContext(this.Request.RequestContext, ctrl);
    var ctrlDescAsync = new ReflectedAsyncControllerDescriptor(ctrl.GetType());
    ctrl.ControllerContext = ctrlContext;

    // get the action
    var actionDesc = ctrlDescAsync.FindAction(ctrlContext, actionName);

    // execute
    ActionResult result;
    if (actionDesc is AsyncActionDescriptor actionDescAsync)
        result = await Task.Factory.FromAsync((asyncCallback, asyncState) => actionDescAsync.BeginExecute(ctrlContext, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "packingSlip", packingSlip }, { "files", files } }, asyncCallback, asyncState), asyncResult => actionDescAsync.EndExecute(asyncResult), null) as ActionResult;
    else
        result = actionDesc.Execute(ctrlContext, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "packingSlip", packingSlip }, { "files", files } }) as ActionResult;

    // return the other action result as the current action result
    return result;
}
```

Now with ASP.NET Core (or .NET 5), `ControllerBuilder` doesn't exist anymore and most of those things changed.

I tried to inject a `IControllerFactory` and use it, but can't find the proper way to use it to call an action knowing the "controllerName" and "actionName". It should also, like before, determine if it was an async action or not and act accordingly.

Comment: But that's exactly what ASP.NET Core routing does. Match names to controllers. You can specify the URL patterns you want, specify which parts should be treated as parameters, and route them to a single Controller that does the actual job

Comment: The code you posted doesn't help explain what you want at all. It's how you wired the old controller, not the controller itself

Comment: Routing is different, it finds the proper controller/action to call from the URL called externally. In my situation, the URL called externally is always the same (/IoT/Run) and contains posted files. Based on the content of the files contained in the request, will call another Controller/Action. And yes, the code posted IS a controller action that serve to redirect to the proper one afterwards.

Comment: Explain what you want to do, not how you think it can be done. Routing is the mechanism that forwards requests to controllers. It's not the inverse, it's the very thing you need to configure to work how you want. There are ways to customize routing beyond pattern matching. I wouldn't be surprised if someone had already built a custom route resolver that used form field values for example. First you have to explain what you actually want though, what data is used for routing, where it comes from

Comment: In this [possibly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302121/header-based-routing-in-asp-net-core) someone asks how to route based on headers. One answer is to create a custom middleware, which gives full access to the request. The other though uses action constraints based on headers to control which action is called based on header values

Comment: Another possibility is to specify an endpoint separate from routing with `MapEndpoints` and process the request there (obviously using a different class, not directly inside Startup.cs) without routing to a controller.

Comment: I believe the question is clear enough. I want to resolve the Controller from the dependency injection and call the proper action (async or not) based on their names I get have as string. I didn't want to confuse the question by adding custom code of my implementation, but the controller name and action name (called PackingSlip here) is coming from one of the file uploaded with a specific name, then deserialized from json into a specific model. I doubt routing customization could do something as complex.

Comment: Again, instead of explaining what you want you wrote how you think it should be done. Why not use action constraints? *Route* constaints? Custom middleware? Endpoints? Why do you assume this has anything to do with dependency injection - DI doesn't affect the pipeline at all. The pipeline is composed of filters and middleware added with `Use` calls, not through registered services

Comment: Which one of those allow to inspect the content of a posted file? That's what I need, call the proper controller/action based no the content of a posted file. As if possible, not impacting the rest of the project when posted to other URL.

Comment: All of them. That is a bad idea though because you end up deserializing and reading the payload twice. If you deserialized the payload once, might as well use it. In that case yes, you can use the DI to pick a service and call it. You don't need a controller for that. Any class would do

Comment: Reason why I call another controller/action is that they can be called independently from the URL routing too. Payload is only deserialized (once) when called from this generic URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by myself.

AspCore have an hidden barely documented extension method that registers controllers in the DI container: [AddControllersAsServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvccoremvcbuilderextensions.addcontrollersasservices?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

```
services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
```

Then you can use `IServiceProvider` to resolve your controllers.

Comment: [Related Andrew Lock article](https://andrewlock.net/new-in-asp-net-core-3-service-provider-validation/)